# Creating a tabulated GUI entry in TCL

Tags: excel, user-interface, tcl, copy-paste

I wish to create a section in my gui where the user can simply copy paste cells from excel into my GUI (rather than individual entry boxes as used at present).

Table is simple, 6 rows and 4 columns entry (would like to have description for each row).

I wondered is someone can point me to an example where I can try/test/play such a entry option, I'm assuming I may need additional tcl/tk modules?

Any help advice, direction to examples would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Anju

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Csaba Nemethi's [tablelist widget](https://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelist.html) yet?  I don't know if that will accept pastes from Excel… but if it doesn't then there probably won't be anything else that does. (The other candidate is [tktable](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tktable), but the likelihood of success is lower.)